# Mocking session and userData with cypress

Tags: next.js, mocking, cypress, e2e-testing, next-auth

currently Iam trying to mock a session for website project with cypress, so the tests are not actually accessing database cause Iam using only 0Auth 3th party login (google and github). I already succesfuly mocked a session so main page shows as logged user. However when I click on my profile, it says: No profile (expected behavior when there is no UserInfo data).

This is my cypress code:
Command:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", () => {
  cy.intercept("/api/auth/session", { fixture: "session.json" }).as("session");
  cy.setCookie("next-auth.session-token", "testcookie");
  Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce("next-auth.session-token");
});
```

Fixture:

```
{
  "user": {
    "name": "test",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "slug": "test0000",
    "id": "strasnedlouhejstring",
    "image": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/112759319?v=4"
  },
  "userInfo": {
    "bio": "Lorem Testum",
    "name": "test",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "slug": "test0000",
    "id": "strasnedlouhejstring",
    "isActive": "true"
  },
  "expires": "3000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "accessToken": "test"
}
```

First test (success):

```
describe("Cypress login", () => {
  it("should provide a valid session", () => {
    cy.login();
    cy.visit("/");
    cy.wait("@session");
    cy.get("#dropdown > div")
      .should("exist")
      .then(() => {
        cy.log("Cypress login successful");
      });
  });
});
```

And finally page rendering:

```
import ProfilePage from "@components/Layout/ProfilePage";
import { User } from "@prisma/client";
import { getUserInfo } from "@scripts/prisma/getUserInfo";
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

const UserProfile = ({ userInfo }: { userInfo: User | null }) => {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  if (userInfo) return <ProfilePage userInfo={userInfo} session={session} />;

  return <h1>No profile</h1>;
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const slug = context.query.userProfile?.toString();

  if (slug) {
    const user = await getUserInfo(slug);

    if (user) {
      return {
        props: { userInfo: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)) },
      };
    }
  }

  return {
    props: { userInfo: null },
  };
};
```

export default UserProfile;

As I said, the condition is always false so i get the message: No Profile.
I spent 2days figuring this out, however not successfuly.